# Present UIPageViewController with Modal Presentation Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

Currently i'm displaying modally a view controller, (embedded in in navigation) with a UIscrollView as subview. I would like to replace the scroll view with an UIPageViewController, but i cant resize the UIPageViewController neither displaying it modally. Solution, ideas?
This is the code that i have now:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *modalNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    UIBarButtonItem *dismiss = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)];
    modalNav.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = dismiss;
    modalNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Comment: what do you mean you can't resize the page view controller? what is the problem?

Comment: because i've created with storyboard the PageViewController and then the ViewController where i defined the layout of the pages. I can resize the ViewController but the modal presentation doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

View controllers can be embedded into one another by using the container view.

Remove your scroll view and put a container view in its place. You'll see that a view controller is embedded it in by default. Delete the embed segue, drag and drop a UIPageViewController into your storyboard and embed it in the container view.

It should look something like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to create a viewcontroller, add uipageviewcontrolller as its sub view.

[image]

Here is my code for Gallery Container Page. I made a push segue to Gallery Container Page so as to avoid navigation troubles (now the parent view controller for PageViewController is Gallery Container.)

```
import UIKit

class GalleryContainerPage: UIViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

private var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    private let contentImages = ["person-icon.jpg",
        "3807343799880.jpg","4701365629867.jpg","4713011921017.jpg"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    private func createPageViewController() {

        let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as! UIPageViewController

        pageController.dataSource = self

        if contentImages.count > 0 {
            let firstController = getItemController(0)!
            let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
            pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

        pageViewController = pageController
        addChildViewController(pageViewController!)

        pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)

    }

private func setupPageControl() {

    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
}
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = viewController as! PageItemController

    if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = viewController as! PageItemController

    if itemController.itemIndex+1 < contentImages.count {
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
    }

    return nil
}

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

    if itemIndex < contentImages.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemController") as! PageItemController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = contentImages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
    }

    return nil
}
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

    return contentImages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        setupPageControl()
        createPageViewController()
    }

}
```